# How can I send multiple documents in nodejs with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm making a query to my database that scans their articles by date. The user selects a date and the server looks up the user's list of written article ids, scans the IDs in the article collection, and then compares the requested date with the 'createdAt' entry of the document. But if there are multiple results, I get a 'cant set headers after they are sent error.' Here is my code:

```
User.find({_id: user._id}, {written: 1}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err
    for (i = 0; i < docs[0].written.length; i++) {
        Articles.find({_id: docs[0].written[i]}, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) throw err
            if (req.query.date == Math.floor(docs[0].createdAt.getTime() / 1000 / 86400)) {
                res.send(docs)
            }
        })
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use something like async (https://github.com/caolan/async) or async-mini (https://github.com/ypocat/async-mini) to do the actual looping for you and then when all the queries have been finished you can respond with an array of articles.

Alternatively you could have a separate function that gets called when everything is done. Here is one way to do what you're looking for using async.each.

```
var articles = [];
User.find({_id: user._id}, {written: 1}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    async.each(docs[0].written, function(doc, done){
        Articles.find({_id: doc}, function (err, articlesFound) {
            if (err) done(err)
            if (req.query.date == Math.floor(doc.createdAt.getTime() / 1000 / 86400)) {
                articles.push(articlesFound);
            }
        });
    }, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        return res.send(articles);
    });

});
```

I think this is what you're after.

Comment: Not working for me, but thanks. I get a Cannot read property 'createdAt' of undefined

Comment: Try doc.createdAt instead.